# Excel: subscript of subscript of a word

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-formatting

Is there a way to write a double subscripted word in Excel? 
For example, I would like to write something like *σ<sub>V<sub>amperometer</sub></sub>*
(i.e., *σ* with a subscript of *V<sub>amperometer</sub>*,
which, itself, is a subscripted expression) in a cell,
but I can only write *σ<sub>Vamperometer</sub>* 
(i.e., *σ* with a subscript of *Vamperometer*). 
I know I could write a formula in a Word fashion
but it gets treated like an image,
while I want it to be like normal text in a cell.

Comment: If you want mathematical formulas to be "like normal text in a cell", I think you'd need to find a font that has the appropriate characteristics. For your edit, see [which stack exchange sites use mathjax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you can't do that in any sort of straightforward way.

P.S. No, Super User doesn't support MathJax.